# Azure data factory IF condition is taking a lot longer to complete than the activities inside it take to complete

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Ok guys, this is a strange one and I can't see anything obvious that would explain it...

I've got a pipeline with an IF condition, this IF condition only has a single 'copy data' activity in it. My confusion is that when monitoring this pipeline as its been triggered by a scheduled trigger, the IF condition often takes a lot longer than the only activity, the 'copy data' activity, that it contains. See screen shot below, where the 'copy data' has only taken 7:47mins but the IF condition has a duration of 16:16mins!?!?!

[image]

Does anyone know what this means, and what might be causing it? Note... the IF condition itself is only a simple check of a variable that has previously been set before...

At first I thought it was because the 'copy data' was queueing, but as there's no input/output information on an IF condition in the monitor I've no idea what's going on. Surely the IF condition isn't taking several minutes to evaluate its expression??

Comment: Kindly let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read the "Duration" time, that it is end-to-end for the pipeline activity. That takes into account all factors like marshaling of your data flow script from ADF to the Spark cluster, cluster acquisition time, job execution, and I/O write time. So  the "Duration" time will be longer than actual execution time.
Therefore, the IF conditional activity is waiting for the response from the copy activity successfully ended and close all diu resources. But there is very little official information about this explanation.:(

By the way, the "Duration" time of the IF condition activity is not chargeable. You can click this link to see run consumption.
[image]

IF condition activity is is billed according to runs at first line. The copy activity is billed according to diu. So we don't need to worry about the "Duration" time of the IF condition activity. :)
[image]